# Why are XML Elements not visible on my emulator?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator

I created a simple Android studio app to practice and learn more. But the elements in XML are not visible in the emulator. How can I fix this problem?

I research but I did not find the answer.

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_welcome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_welcome"
    android:textSize="26sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_instructions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/text_instruction"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_feet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="4"
        android:hint="@string/edit_feet"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_inchee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:ems="4"
        android:hint="@string/edit_inches"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_pounds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:ems="4"
        android:hint="@string/edit_pounds"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/boutton_calculate_bmi"
    android:text="@string/boutton_cal_bmi"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/text_result"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
package com.applike.bmi;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   TextView text_result;
   EditText edit_feet , edit_inches , edit_pounds;
   Button button_calculate_bmi;



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       /*
       edit_feet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_feet);
       edit_inches = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_inchee);
       edit_pounds = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_pounds);
       button_calculate_bmi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_calculate_bmi);
       text_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_result);


       button_calculate_bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               String results="Results: ";
              // int feet = Integer.parseInt(edit_feet.getText().toString());
               if(edit_feet.getText().length() == 0){
                   edit_feet.setError("Please enter a #.");
                   results += "Oops! There was an error. ";
               }
               else if(edit_feet.getText().length() > 1){
                   edit_feet.setError("Too many digits");
                   results += "Our records indicate that your cannot possibily" +
                           " be thay tall. ";
               }
               else {
                   results += "The length of feet is " +
                           edit_feet.getText().length();
               }
               text_result.setText(results);
           }
       });

*/
   }
}
```

[image: Android Studio screenshot. XML preview showing layout, emulator is blank]

Is there is something wrong in my XML file?
Please provide me solution for this. How should I handle this?

Comment: pls check image

Comment: Can you also post your `MainActivity.java` code, specifically the part that inflates the layout?

Comment: try to use another emulator or device phone also post the `MainActivity.java`

Comment: i try but not working

Comment: @Omid Did any of the answers below help you?

Comment: @MichaelDodd With respect to you - I have solved my problem - Thank you for your importance

Comment: @Omid No worries, in which case if you problem wasn't solved by any of the existing answers, would you mind posting your own solution as an answer? Just so we can help anyone else who has this proble in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You're not inflating your layout within your Activity, thus why it's not being displayed. You need to use the `setContentView()` function within `onCreate()` to inflate your layout like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your layout in **onCreate()** method, like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not inflating your layout within your Activity.You need to use the setContentView() method within onCreate() to inflate your layout like so it will visible on device:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_new); //activity_main_new defines your xml layout.
```

If you want to inflate your layout within your Fragment.You need to define your layout in onCreateView() method of Fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.homecredit, container, false); //where home credit is your layout file, container is root layout and attachToRoot is a boolean value
}
```